# Epoch and wireshark capture

Tags: c, wireshark, epoch, wireshark-dissector

I have a .pkt sniffer capture. When I read each and every packet within the capture from my C application, I observe a radio header appended. The radio header contains the time in epoch for each and every packet. I would like to find out the time difference between two packets in terms of milliseconds. I am not sure how to diff two epoch values and find out the time difference in milliseconds. Please help me with this.

Comment: You need to provide way more details about what data format you're dealing with.

Comment: I didn't quite get your question - I need the difference in the time between two frames in msecs. My application is written in C.

Comment: What protocol are you talking about?  What type of frames?  What's the frame format?   What are the units of the timestamps?

Comment: I am talking of the 802.11 protocol and the frames correspond to this protocol. The units of the timestamps is in Epoch.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a .pkt sniffer capture.

What is a ".pkt sniffer capture"?  Did you use Wireshark to capture the packets?  If so, then it's either a pcap or a pcap-ng capture.

> The radio header contains the time in epoch for each and every packet.

In most sniffer formats, the time stamp for packets is part of a "record header", not part of a radio-information header.  For 802.11 captures, some capture file formats might provide a radio-information header that includes the 802.11 Timing Synchronization Function timer, but that timer doesn't have a specified epoch.

The epoch for the packet time stamp depends on the capture file format.  pcap and pcap-ng use the UN*X epoch of January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC, as pcap was originally used on UN*X and pcap-ng is influenced by pcap.  Other file formats might, for example, use the Windows FILETIME epoch of January 1, 1601, 00:00:00 "UTC" (using the [proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_Calendar)), or some other time origin.

But if all you want is to

> find out the time difference between two packets in terms of milliseconds

then the epoch is irrelevant - if a time is represented as "*X* seconds since some epoch) (where *X* isn't necessarily an integer; it could have a fractional part), then the time between "*X* seconds since the epoch" and "*Y* seconds since the epoch" is *X* - *Y*, and the epoch itself cancels out.

The big issue, then, is how is "seconds since some epoch" represented.  An integral count of seconds?  An integral count of {nanoseconds, tenths of microseconds, microseconds, milliseconds, etc.}?  A combination of seconds and {nanoseconds, microseconds, etc.}?  That's why we'd need to know whether this is a file-format time stamp or an 802.11 TSFT and, if it's a file-format time stamp, what file format that is.

If, as you seem to indicate, this is a Wireshark capture (i.e., a capture made with Wireshark, not just a capture that Wireshark happens to be able to read - it can read captures from programs that don't use its native pcap or pcap-ng format), then the file format is pcap or pcap-ng (in which case the epoch is the Epoch, i.e. January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTS) and the time stamp is either 32-bit seconds since the Epoch and 32-bit microseconds since that second, for pcap, or a 64-bit count of units since the Epoch (the units are specified by the Interface Description Block for the interface on which the packet in question was captured; the default is microseconds).

To calculate the difference between the time stamps of two pcap packets, in microseconds, take the difference between the seconds values, multiply it by 1,000,000, and add to it the difference between the microseconds values (both differences are signed).  To convert that to milliseconds, divide it by 1,000.

To calculate the difference between the time stamps of two pcap-ng packets, take the difference between the time stamp values; that's a count of fractions of a second, where the fraction is defined by the specified value in the Interface Description Block.  To convert that to milliseconds, adjust as appropriate based on what the fraction is (for example, if it's microseconds, divide it by 1,000).

To calculate the difference between the TSFT values of two 802.11 packets, just subtract one value from the other; the TSFT value, at least for radiotap, is in microseconds, so, to convert it to milliseconds, divide it by 1,000.

Answer (score 0):

"Epoch" isn't a unit or format; it's a point in time. Specifically, it's midnight UTC of January 1st, 1970.

[Unix timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) are just the number of seconds that have passed since that time. Subtract the smaller one from the larger to find the difference in seconds, and multiply by 1000 to get the number of milliseconds.